# 404 for wp-content when wordpress is running on /blog in nginx

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have setup a wordpress site on ubuntu 20.04 with nginx.
on / there is a SSR application and the blog is running on /blog.
But WP site is not able to access any file from wp-content.

Sample conf file from nginx:

```
location ^~ /blog {
    # index index.php;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    autoindex  off;
    root /var/www/html/blog;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    location ~* \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;

    }

}
location / {

      proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

SSR application is working perfectly. All the blogs and internal pages are working fine in WP, but anything from wp-content gives 404.

Is there something missing from the configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I did some digging and some changes in the configuration, I was able to successfully configure the website as I wanted to.
Here's the config file:

```
location ^~ /blog {
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    autoindex  off;
    # root /var/www/html/blog;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$is_args$args;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
```

Instead of using `root /var/www/html/blog;` I added `/blog` in the try_files and all resolved.
If I only added `blog` in front of index.php, then the internal links were not working. All the routes will work with `/blog/index.php$is_args$args;`

Comment: There is no point to use `^~` prefix in your configuration, simple `location /blog` does the same.